# nginx $fastcgi_file_name not set?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

After googling for info on fastcgiwrap, I came to the conclusion that ths following config should work:

```
location ~ /sec-bin/.+\.pl$ {
    gzip off;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/site/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

However it does not, I get the "403 cannot get script name" error. If I change that block to

```
location ~ /sec-bin/(.+\.pl)$ {
    gzip off;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/site/cgi-bin/$1;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

I don't fully understand why it works this way or the implications of doing so, any ideas?

Comment: What is the path and name of the script file? In example (1), you have `/cgi-bin/` repeated twice, and in example (2), you knock off the `.pl` extension.

Comment: Apologies, my example config was bad, I have corrected that now. The scripts live outside of the document root in /usr/lib/site/cgi-bin where various .pl files exist, the url to them is not cgi-bin but sec-bin so what I want to do is get the .pl file from the URL and point it at /usr/lib/site/cgi-bin. I think I must be misunderstanding what $fastcgi_script_name is being set to. I assume from your comment that it's set to the entire location definition?

Comment: Unless you do something to change it, it’s set to the same value as $uri.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. I had mistakenly assumed that $fastcgi_script_name was only the last part of the uri (the script name itself).